# Error while uploading image through Laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-7

I am trying to upload image but it gives me following error

[image]

I've also added extension=php_fileinfo.dll in my php.ini file but still it gives me the same error as above image.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure it's enabled? You may have edited the wrong `php.ini` as some environments can have multiple files. Put `dd(get_loaded_extensions());` in your PHP code somewhere to see if `fileinfo` is there, or alternatively you can run `php -m`

Comment: after configuration change you have to restart your xampp or wampp. If this error again then image upload file permission eanble

Comment: @A.ANoman how image upload file permissions can be enabled?

Comment: Follow this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unable-to-guess-the-mime-type-as-no-guessers-are-available-did-you-enable-the-php-fileinfo-extension

Comment: @A.ANoman still giving the same error

Comment: @Nathan I put dd(get_loaded_extensions()); in my code and it shows me 35 files in which fileinfo is not there. Now what I do?

Comment: What code are you exactly using to do the image upload?

Comment: Type `php --ini` within your project terminal and check for the `Loaded Configuration File`, this is `php.ini` file used by your CLI. Make sure the extension is uncommented within that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have edited the wrong `php.ini` file, as some environments can have multiple `php.ini` files due to different configurations of PHP. To check to see if the PHP version you are using is actually loading the extension, you can type `php -m` within your project terminal to see loaded modules, alternatively you can `dd(get_loaded_extensions());` within your PHP somewhere to see similar results.

If your extension is not loaded, it most likely means you have edited the wrong file. Therefore you can type `php --ini` within your project terminal and check for the `Loaded Configuration File`. This is the `php.ini` file used by your CLI. Make sure the extension is uncommented within that file.